# "object reference required" eventhandling program

Tags: c#, timer, event-handling

Can someone please tell me why I'm getting the error "object reference is required" for  the call to CheckForMessage" in the last line. Thanks.

```
class Program
{
    private void CheckForMessage(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine("Checking for new Messages");
        if ((random.Next(9) == 0)) { Console.WriteLine("hello mum"); } else { Console.WriteLine("no message"); }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         Timer pollTimer=new Timer(100);
    pollTimer.Elapsed+=new ElapsedEventHandler(CheckForMessage);


    }
}
```

Comment: remember to start the time class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to call an instance method (`CheckForMessage`) without an instance of a class. Just change it to a static method instead:

```
private static void CheckForMessage(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
```

Comment: I see, so if it is not part of a class I instantiate then use the static keyword.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting a compile error "An object reference is required to access non-static member.."
What happens if you change the CheckForMessage to a static method.

Comment: That wasn't the error but I had to change it to static.  Thanks astro